# Matrix operations on labeled arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix, python-xarray

I have a system with a linearised set of equations, such that the time-update operation can be performed by a matrix multiplication, `y' = Ay`, but I would also like to be able to index `y` using the names of the state variables, e.g. `y['vel']`. Is there a way to index in this way without losing the ability to do matrix operations?

Things I've considered:

1. np.recarray - Looks promising, but can you still perform matrix operations (e.g. `inner`)? How easy is it to construct a 2D object with the same indices?
2. Pandas - Supports labeled columns, but isn't really appropriate for row-based operations in my experience. Doesn't seem to support matrix operations on rows.
3. A standard ndarray, with indexes stored as named variables - `idx_vel = 3; y[idx_vel]`. This would definitely work, but seems... inelegant...

Comment: How does your data look like?

Comment: How about 3) but using `enum.IntEnum` would that be pretty enough?

Comment: Really need some example data and desired output.  Maybe take a look at xarray?

Comment: The state vector, `y`, is a N x 1 array of floats, while the evolution matrix, `A`, is N x N floats. `y` is constructed mathematically from a list of properties (eg. `y = [pos, vel, acc]`), and I wish to return the value of the properties with name-based indexing, rather than numerical indexes, so it easier to add/alter properties going forwards.

Comment: I mean, construct an ACTUAL (small example) array and show ACTUAL (small example) results.  E.g. `arr = np.array( [[1,2],[3,4]] )` and show operations on that.  Stack overflow generally works best with specific examples rather than abstract discussions.

Comment: How about using a `dict` for your indices, i.e. `keys=['pos', 'vel', 'acc']` and then `mapping={key : val for val, key in enumerate(keys)}`? Then you could just access your array with `y[mapping['vel']]` ...